# Tokenized Sublime Project Name

Tags: sublimetext3, project

Is it possible in Sublime Text 3 to make a project have a name with tokens in it where the tokens would be parts of the path. I am trying to produce a name like the following.

```
${Product} (${Branch})
```

The branch would be the name of folder I added the to the project and the Product would be the name of the folder 1 level up from this so the path would look like this.

```
Products\\Product\\Branch
```

Here is an example of what I would think the project file would look like if these tokens existed or if there is a means for me to define them.

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "name": "${Product} (${Branch})",
            "path": "Products\\Product1\\Branch"
        },
        {
            "name": "${Product} (${Branch})",
            "path": "Products\\Product2\\Branch"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Out of interest why would you want to?

Comment: @mattst I was adding a bunch of our our nugat packages to the same project so that I could search them using regex in sublime and all of the branches that I add are named trunk so I just have 20 trunk folders and I figured if I could use replacement tokens like this it would make it easier then me manually modifying each of the name variables. I also have a bunch of folders named RC and main and it's hard to tell different products apart when I'm looking at them to drill down into the one I want to.

Comment: As MattST said, this isn't directly possible (i.e. Sublime won't do it on its own). However the plugin API allows you to access and modify the project file so a plugin could do the swap for you, though it would be a destructive change (if that matters). You could get around that by storing extra metadata in the project, though.

Comment: @OdatNurd I am not familiar with sublime plugin development what do you mean by destructive in this case? The extra metadata is a good idea, so based on the context I am guessing destructive means it won't work with other sublime instances without the plug-in?

Comment: @MaxYoung Essentially the idea is that the plugin would read the project and replace the `name` with an expanded version, but it would do it in place. So afterwards if you were to look at the project file, the `name` field would be the name and no longer have the variables in it. That is, going forward you wouldn't know that there were any variables there, if that matters. If it does then they would need to be recorded elsewhere in the project (like if you wanted to change the format for example).

Comment: @OdatNurd I see what you mean by destructive now, thank you